# WebApp input field gets overlayed by iOS Keyboard (only on iPad Air)

Tags: html, ios, css, ipad, web

I developed a WebApp for a customer, which should be used with an iPad Air. The issue occurs on a form with several text-input fields. The form is designed to fit on a page without scrollbars on mobile devices (smartphones or tablets) in portrait mode (vertical). On my devices (Android Smartphone, Android Tablet and iPad Pro) everything works fine, but on the iPad Air of the customer the following issue occurs:

Whenever he tries to select an input field in the bottom of the page, the iPad keyboard overlays this input field and the user is not able to scroll up to make the input field visible. So the user has to fill the input field, while he is not able to see what he is typing, because the input field is behind the keyboard (obviously not optimal).

I would expect, that the keyboard is shrinking the web view and scrolling the input field to a visible area, which is the case on my iPadPro.

What do I have to do to get the expected behavior on the iPad Air?